# VSCode node.js debugging with symlink to another project folder

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have two folders in my project: `api` and `db-service`

`Api` contains the api routes and `db-service` contains the database logic.
I linked `db-service` in `api` with `npm link db-service`.

When I set breakpoints in `db-service` and start debugging the `api` these are ignored (*breakpoint set but not yet bound*).
However when I set breakpoints in `api/node_modules/db-service` they work as expected.
To make things more clear, the `api` runs in a docker-container.

My launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Attach API",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 58581,
            "address": "localhost",
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "localRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/api",
            "remoteRoot": "/usr/src/app",
            "protocol": "inspector"
        },
```

docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  api:
    build: ../api
    command: nodemon -L --inspect=0.0.0.0:58581 --preserve-symlinks
```

Is there a way to tell vscode to recognize the breakpoints set in `db-service`?

PS: Another thing I noticed that if I open a file in `node_modules/db-service` and the same file in `db-service` they are not automatically refreshed and vscode tells me to merge them.

Comment: hey @user547995 were you able to accomplish this?

Comment: not really :/ i can debug either one but not both at the same time

Comment: yeah, I'm in the same spot. Thank you.